How to disable color in Lerna logs?
I'm running Lerna in Jenkins I can't find a way to disable colors. The logs are garbled with additional color codes.
Log snip from Jenkins:
[37;40mlerna[0m [0m[36;40mnotice[0m [0m[35mcli[0m v8.1.3

The same line when run locally:

I'm running a script in a Docker container. I have tried to disable colors with environment variables.
docker run -t --rm --name "node-alpine" \
    -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/frontend \
    -w /usr/src/frontend/ \
    -e FORCE_COLOR=0 \
    -e NPM_CONFIG_PROGRESS=false \
    -e NPM_CONFIG_SPIN=false \
    -e NPM_CONFIG_COLOR=false \
    -e NO_COLOR=true \
    "node:20.13.1-alpine" \
    /bin/sh -c \
    "sh version-update.sh"

version-update.sh
#!/bin/sh

git_version=0.4.0

echo "Update Front-end Version to $git_version"
yarn
npx lerna init
npx lerna version $git_version --yes --no-changelog --no-git-tag-version


Sorry, don't know anything about Lerna, but instead of disabling colours you might want to display them properly in Jenkins log using the AnsiColor plugin. Install it (no Jenkins restart required), set Global color map to xterm in System Configuration, and you are done - proper colours instead of ansi codes.
